# load HTML when click a button GWT

Tags: gwt

how to load the other HTML page when i click a button? i'm using GWT 2.0.3.

```
        p.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
              public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // is there a syntax to load other HTML?
            }
       });
```

thanks before, Rafael.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use GWT's history mechanism, then you want to look at `History.newItem("newPage");`

If you want to jump to a totally new URL (and navigate outside your application) then you can use `Window.Location.replace("newURL");`.

Finally, if you just want to change the page within your application but are not using history, then you probably want to do something like:

```
RootPanel.get().clear()
RootPanel.get().add( widgetForNewPage );
```